# Cyclotomic Integers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})$ be the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining all $p-$power roots of unity.

My question is : how to show that the the ring of integes of $K,$ $O_K$ is not a Dedekind domain ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, I think there's been enough discussion in the comments to turn it into a proper answer.

As Alex noted, our goal is really to prove that $\mathcal O_K$ is not Noetherian. To do so, we will prove that some rational prime $\ell$ "factors into infinitely many factors" in $\mathcal O_K$.

We will do this for $p=\ell$. Recall that 
$$(p)=(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}=(1-\zeta_{p^2})^{p^2-p}=\ldots=(1-\zeta_{p^n})^{\varphi(p^n)}=\ldots$$
Then we have an increasing chain 
$$(p)\subset(1-\zeta_p)\subset(1-\zeta_{p^2})\subset\ldots\subset(1-\zeta_{p^n})\subset\ldots$$
and thus the ring is not Noetherian. One can think of this as a failure of unique factorization into prime ideals, which characterizes Dedekind rings. In this case, the uniqueness is not the problem, but rather the existence of a factorization in the first place--we can keep on factoring and factoring $(p)$ but will never get all the way down to prime ideals.

It turns out that the only possible choice for $\ell$ was $p$: Suppose $\ell\neq p$ and let $n$ be the greatest integer so that $\zeta_{p^n}\in\mathbb Q_\ell$. Then $[\mathbb Q_\ell(\zeta_{p^{n+m}}):\mathbb Q_\ell]=\frac{\varphi(p^{n+m})}{\varphi(p^n)}=[\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^{n+m}}):\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})]$, so primes lying above $\ell$ in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})$ remain prime in larger subextensions.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** It's not Noetherian. Try and show that above some prime of $\mathbb{Z}$ there are infinitely many primes. Check this by arguing that you can find extensions of arbitrarily large degree where the prime splits.

**EDIT:** Of course, you knew that it had to be non-Noetherianess since normality and dimension $1$ are true for any integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand you can explain more!

Comment: @Amine Which part are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: @Amine You need to take some prime in a finite subextension (for example, a prime in $\mathbb Q$), and show that its extension to $K$ does not have a unique factorization. Specifically, you can keep factoring this ideal into "smaller" and "smaller" numbers (ie, larger ideals), so the ring is not Noetherian.

Comment: how to show that $O_K$ is not Noetherian??

Comment: @Amine You know that if $\mathcal{O}_K$ were a Dedekind domain, then any prime of $p$ would be contained in finitely many primes of $\mathcal{O}_K$. But, try and show that you can find subextensions $K/L/\mathbb{Q}$ with $L$ a Number field, and $p$ splits in $\mathcal{O}_L$. Since these must lift to distinct primes upstairs (since we're in dimension $1$) you can get infinitely many distinct primes containing $p$.

Comment: You also get an infinite ascending chain `above' the ramified prime $p$. Hint: in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ this is generated by $1-\zeta_p$. Do you know what happens to that prime in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})?$ Keep going!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That also works!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, I do not know!

Comment: $$(1-\zeta_p)\subset(1-\zeta_{p^2})\subset\cdots$$

Comment: My idea is to show that there is an ideal of $O_K$  not finitely generated ??

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it is a non-stationary chain ideals of $O_K$ ???

Comment: The idea is (following Alex) to prove non-noetherianity. And, yes, this violates the ascending chain condition.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks

Comment: @AlexYoucis thanks

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think that the thing that made my solution more natural (to me) than yours, is that it's what you get when you try to show that (most) fibers of the map $\text{Spec}\mathcal{O}_K\to\text{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ are infinite. Of course, this shows you how simple it is to create examples of integral and non-finite morphisms of (even affine) schemes which don't have finite fibers.

Comment: @BrettFrankel thanks

Comment: Wait a minute. I don't believe the claim by @AlexYoucis that there exists a rational prime which is infinitely split in the extension. Alex, can you exhibit such a prime?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler You're right. Working locally, $\mathbb Q_\ell$ will contain the $p^n$th roots of $1$ but not the $p^{n+1}$st roots, so every in finite subextension of $\mathbb Q_\ell(\zeta_{p^n})$ will increase the residual degree of $p$ but not the number of primes above it.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Please see my comment to David. Tchebotarev tells us that there are primes that split into arbitrarily many distinct primes in $K$, but a simple local argument (see previous comment) shows that no prime will "split completely" in $K$, which is what your argument requires.

Comment: @BrettFrankel Can you explain to me how it can be shown that the extension of $p$ in $K$  does not have a unique factorization

Comment: @Amine It suffices to show that $(p)=(1-\zeta_{p^n})^{\varphi(p^n)}$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function, so that $p$ is totally ramified in any finite subextension. It's a good exercise to try working this out on your own, but if you get stuck there will be an explanation in your favorite number theory text.

Comment: @Amine From this, you can conclude, as Jyriki noted, that $$(p)\subset (1-\zeta_p)\subset (1-\zeta_{p^2})\subset\ldots$$ and thus $\mathcal O_K$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: @BrettFrankel yes I know this result  ($(p)=(1-{\zeta_{p^{n}}})^{\phi(p^n)} $) but how to show from this that the extension of $p$ in $K$ does not have a unique factorization ?